# Firefox plugin to un-Google-fy links and copy them to the clipboard/pasteboard?

Tags: firefox, google-apps, hyperlink

I use Firefox for browsing and Google for searching. When Google returns search results, it does so with a Google-fied link that includes additional metadata.

I'm looking for a plugin that I can hover over a link in Google search results, and copy the un-Google-fied link to the clipboard or pasteboard. The copy should occur after right clicking the link and selecting a context menu (similar to what we have now with "Copy Link Location" or similar in browsers).

For example, searching for Bernstein's paper *The Poly1305-AES message-authentication code* returns <http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CB8QFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fiacr.org%2Farchive%2Ffse2005%2F35570033%2F35570033.ps&ei=TW8XVZpvyJ-DBIf3gbAJ&usg=AFQjCNENRpiTiJhpZ48mnw2yW9ikHVC2Bg&sig2=J2mdCFE9CsM2BsRNhqbrpw&bvm=bv.89381419,d.eXY>. The real link is simply <http://iacr.org/archive/fse2005/35570033/35570033.ps>.

Is there such a plugin for Firefox?

Comment: "The copy should occur after right clicking the link": Is this mandatory? Or would a solution that disables this Google tracking method entirely be okay, too?

Comment: @unor - an undecorated link/URL after right clicking/copy is all that's desired. A solution that disables the tracking would be OK, too as long as I can get the un-Google-fied link off the clipboard when I copy it. Tracking is not a concern to me for this (I know its important, and I would use an anonymizer like Tor if it was).

Comment: Did my answer end up working for you?

Comment: @blackwind  - no, but I did not try it because I don't use Greasemonkey. I use Firefox and Opera (mostly Firefox, and that's why I asked about it only).

Answer (score 4):

[Google Tracking-B-Gone](https://greasyfork.org/en/scripts/1810-google-tracking-b-gone) for [Greasemonkey](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/greasemonkey/) will convert all Google links back to their original values, allowing you to copy as you would any other link.

Answer (score 1):

The [Google Privacy](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/google-privacy) add-on will turn tracked URLs into normal ones, which can then be copied normally.

> This add-on shows tracking-free links or optionally replaces the
>   results with those links. Websites supported (for now) are Google,
>   YouTube, Yahoo!, Bing and Facebook.

Comment: Thanks @nstenz. I just tried the Google Privacy add-on. After restarting Firefox, I still got the Google-fied or decorated link. So it looks like this does not satisfy requirements.

Comment: Sorry- I thought I replied to this a long time ago, but the extension is configurable. By default, I believe it adds an additional link with the bare URL, but leaves the original as well.

Answer (score 0):

The **[Don't track me Google](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/dont-track-me-google1/)** Firefox extension (which is also a [Chrome extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/dont-track-me-google/gdbofhhdmcladcmmfjolgndfkpobecpg?hl=en)) does what you are looking for.

> At the Google Search engine, search results are converted to an ugly link upon click. This link enables tracking for Google.
>
> For example, the search entry
>
> - http://www.google.com/
>     (when searching for "Google") will be replaced with:
> - https://encrypted.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=Google&source=web&cd=8&sqi=2&ved=0CFgQFjAH&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com%2F&ei=Ej__TrCkJo2bOrSs2aIE&usg=AFQjCNG5-9Jej-ukVeakTgwonqt2narbYg&sig2=f9f1dWcZoj6ZUC2Zxy9y2g
>
> This addon removes Google's link-conversion/tracking feature. This
>   speeds up loading search results and allows you to normally copy
>   links.

[image]